# JMeter: Need to send all values in a CSV File to different variables in a request body, based on some criteria

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter, http-post

I have a CSV file, which has some user details, like their employee id (123456) and email id (abc@xyz.com). The employee id/email id of the users are present in the first column, and the second column contains the type of the id (employee id/email id). It looks like below:

| id | idType |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | empid |
| abc@xyz.com | emailid |
| 111111 | empid |
| ghi@xyz.com | emailid |

In the body of the HTTP request (JSON), I need to pass these values to different variables, based on the id type given in the CSV file. For example, if the id type id empid, I need to pass those values to empid array; and so on. I want the passed values to look like below:

`{"empid":["123456", "111111"], "emailid":["abc@xyz.com", "ghi@xyz.com"]}`

If the value is passed to a single variable, I can achieve the same using User Parameters Preprocessor, but this requirement is a bit tricky. Is there any method to pass the values to the request in the above mentioned format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), i.e.

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the request which needs to have this JSON body generated
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def lines = new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().drop(1)

   def empIds = lines.findAll { line -> line.split(',')[1] == 'empid' }.collect { line -> line.split(',')[0] }
   def emailIds = lines.findAll { line -> line.split(',')[1] == 'emailid' }.collect { line -> line.split(',')[0] }

   def payload = ['empid': empIds, 'emailid': emailIds]

   vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. Use `${payload}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) reference in the "Body Data" tab of the HTTP Request sampler (or wherever you need to use this JSON)

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-templates)